# Why Spring @Autowired ApplicationContext appContext is null?

Tags: spring, facelets

I have Spring bean with annotations:

```
@Named
@Scope("session")
```

And this bean property:

```
@Autowired
ApplicationContext appContext;
```

The Spring configuration file has entry (that works for other anotations/injections):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package.name" />
```

Why appContext is null after such code and configuration?

I am trying to get ApplicationContext (to call getBean(...) on it) and this can be quite involved task (judging from other discussions) in previous Spring versions (e.g. one is required to get ServletContext in Spring web application to create ApplicationContext and getting ServletContext can be quite involved task for beans that don't directly access HTTP Request objects). In Spring 3.x, as I understand, simple @Autwired injection can be used. How AppContext can be accessed?

Comment: rather than using application context better to use @Autowired to inject/get bean

Answer (score 2):

Here the first problem is you are using `@Named` which is Java EE annotation and as for as I know Spring yet to support Java EE annotations. Hence instead of using `@Named` try to use Spring annotation @Service, @Component, @Repository etc.

Here is the example for you I have used JSF Managed bean as well to show how to integrate beans.

```
@ManagedBean(name="myBacking")
@RequestScoped
public class MyBacking {

    private String myText;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{mySpring}")
    MySpringBean mySpring;

    public String getMyText() {
        myText = mySpring.getText();
        return myText;
    }

    public void setMyText(String myText) {
        this.myText = myText;
    }

    public MySpringBean getMySpring() {
        return mySpring;
    }

    public void setMySpring(MySpringBean mySpring) {
        this.mySpring = mySpring;
    }


}

@Service("mySpring")
@Scope("request")
public class MySpringBean {

    @Autowired
    MySecond mySecond;

    public String getText(){
        return "Hello KP" + mySecond.appObj();
    }

}


@Service
@Scope("request")
public class MySecond {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public String appObj(){
        MyThrid mythird =(MyThrid)applicationContext.getBean("myThrid");
        return "My Second Bean calld "+ mythird.getTxt();
    }
}

@Service
public class MyThrid {

    public String getTxt(){
        return "from thrid Bean";
    }
}
```